# Double Curly Braces in HTML source when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

The html of a webpage I am trying to scrape includes the following tag:

```
<a href="" class="header-see-reviews-link">{{rates}} avaliações</a>
```

The information I am interested in seems to be replaced by {{rates}} when I parse it, but when I view it on the webpage using developer tools the {{rates}} is replaced with 4.6, which is the value I want. Is there any way to retrieve this 4.6 value?

As I understand it, this is not the same as simply handling javascript using Selenium since this data is not contained anywhere in the source.

Comment: http://www.americanas.com.br/lojista/Eletronica+Santana/60717899000190  interested in where it says "2000 avaliacoes"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any calls we can replicate to get the data, you will have to use something like selenium